# Does a HTTPS server implementation exist that runs on the ESP32 version of NodeMCU?

Tags: esp32, nodemcu

I'm hoping to add HTTPS server support to an ESP32 based NodeMCU project. Is anyone aware of an implementation or HTTP overlay that enables HTTPS support?

Comment: [Googling "esp32 https server"](https://www.google.com/search?q=esp32+https+server&oq=esp32+https+server) didn't find you anything?

Comment: @romkey by "NodeMCU" Kit refers to the NodeMCU (Lua) firmware I guess; the tag is correctly set.

Comment: @kit-klein I am personally not aware of any such implementation.

Comment: @MarcelStör people commonly use “nodemcu” to refer to certain breakout boards or to the LUA environment. Not clear which the OP is referring to.

Comment: @romkey So true, I'm aware of that. The SO 'nodemcu' tag is "reserved" (rather _intended_ I guess) for the Lua firmware.

Comment: @MarcelStör is correct. I'm referring the the Lua environment associated with the tag.